# How to remove all wrappers before new range.surroundContents(span)

Tags: javascript, range

On my page I use searching for a text and highlighting it like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var inputValue = this.value;
    var tableTDs = document.querySelectorAll('table td');
    for(var i = 0; i < tableTDs.length; i++) {
        tableTDs[i].scrollIntoView();
        if(document.createRange) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            var childs = tableTDs[i].childNodes;
            for(var n = 0; n < childs.length; n++) {
                var childNode = childs[n];
                if(childNode.nodeValue) { // if child is a text node
                    var childValue = childNode.nodeValue;
                } else { // if child is a nested element e.g. a link
                    var childValue = childNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var childNode = childNode.firstChild;
                }
                if(childValue && childValue.indexOf(inputValue) != -1) {
                    range.setStart(childNode, childValue.indexOf(inputValue));
                    range.setEnd(childNode, childValue.indexOf(inputValue) + inputValue.length);
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                    range.surroundContents(span);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<table>
    <tr><td>First cell</td><td>Second cell and <a href="#!">link anchor</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

If I want to find for example the word "anchor", I type "a", next "n" and next "c" and I see two highlightings, but not one highlighting of "anc".

So as I can understand, I need to remove all the wrappers before new `range.surroundContents()`

How can I resolve the issue?

---

**UPDATED**

Ok, the first possible solution is adding before `tableTDs[i].scrollIntoView()` the following code

```
tableTDs[i].innerHTML = tableTDs[i].innerHTML.replace(/<span style=\"background-color: yellow;\">/g,'');
tableTDs[i].innerHTML = tableTDs[i].innerHTML.replace(/<\/span>/g,'');
```

But is there something better?

Comment: can you post a fiddle..?

Comment: Added a snippet

Comment: I think, that you have got mistake in loop, try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLxj3wbc/6/ and try to write "cell" into search input ..